# Understanding MVC using Observer in Java

Tags: java, model-view-controller, observer-pattern

I study Java MVC from [this example](http://www.austintek.com/mvc/).

If the **View** is [Observer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html) and the **Model** [Observable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html), why the `Observer.update` method accepts Observable in the first parameter? If the View worked with the Model (relying on some of its methods), it wouldn't be reusable. Shouldn't be the second parameter the only thing that the View should work with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why the Observer.update method accepts Observable in the first parameter?

The observable is what initiates the update call, and it passes a reference to itself in this call so that the observer knows without doubt who is making this call. Imagine what would happen if the observer is observing several observables at once. This type of parameter passing will help eliminate confusion as to the source of this call. It's really little different from a passing a reference to the calling object in a Swing ChangeEvent object or an ActionEvent object.

Comment: But the View and the Model should be only loosely coupled, shouldn't they? If I get it right, the View should only update its contents, it's not its business to sniff who is calling, it ensures the Controller. Please correct me if I'm wrong. I know that in some situation the Observer needs to know who is it observing, but not in the MVC described above, right?

Comment: @Jan: the view doesn't have to know who is calling, but sometimes it does. View is almost always more tightly coupled than the model which is almost always extremely loosely coupled.

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't use Java's Observer/Observable for my MVC but rather usually "roll my own" using PropertyChangeSupport.